# Why a form would automatically resubmitted when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, refresh

Does anyone know why a form would automatically resubmitted when the page is refreshed?

I an setting a javascript cookie to test whether or not to refresh the page - if it's 'YES' then do it etc... This is action on the body load event.  The form submits through a hidden iFrame.

The trouble is, when this occurs the 'buy' button (submit) form on the page is resubmitted and thus returns to the page it's just returned from (the basket). This happens in FF but not in IE.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what server side language are you using to catch the POST?

Comment: If it was PHP I could give you the lines of code that would do it =)

Comment: I could probably follow the code if you want to put then up.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to address this issue is to monkey with the POST recipient:

After the catching script has done all of the processing required by the POST, throw a `Location:`  header that redirects to the the currently requested URI. This has the affect of the browser recognizing the final destination as not having received a POST, and therefore refreshing won't resubmit the POST.

### PHP Example

#### page.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Do some stuff
    header('Location: page.php');
    // The second time around _POST won't have any data,
    // so there's not worry of an infinite loop
    exit;
}
?>
<h1>Hi, I will never try to resubmit POST data!</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Shad.  Sorry I'm not sure has to do this. Can you elaborate a little on how and where to put the Location header?  It's late here and it's been a very long day...

Answer (score 0):

FireFox is designed to save your forms/inputs, which includes submit buttons.
This is really helpful when developing sites with forms so you don't have to keep filling them out, but it can get in the way sometimes, but it's a browser feature, not a code issue.

Comment: That was quick!  Is there anything I can do to prevent it happening?

Comment: I think there's a setting to turn it off in FireFox somewhere - probably inside the hidden settings - but that would only turn it off for your browser and anybody else who uses FireFox would run into the same issue.
Because it's a browser thing and happens before any code is processed, you can't stop it with code.

Comment: Francis, what about temporarily setting the action proerty to something that won't work and the after the page has finished loading setting it back?  I'm clutching at straws here.

Comment: Right now what I'm doing on a search form to get around this issue is when the submit button is pushed, it submits the form through AJAX, which returns an id, then the javascript redirects to a new page with a search_id which contains all their search data in the database. That way, not only can the user refresh the page, but can get back to the page with their form information already filled out.

Answer (score 0):

If you POSTed to get to the current page (instead of a post then a response.redirect to GET the current page), when you hit the browser's refresh button, it's going to re-POST.  I'm not sure how that relates to your hidden Iframe issue, though.  (It seems I'm duplicating what Shad just said, in essence).